# Errors Finding Values in Other dfs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning. I was having issues using iterrows to find matching values in other dfs. It's both detecting matches where none exist and not finding matches where they do exist.

```
data1 = {
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "Value": [11, 21, 23, 44, 1]
}

data2 = {
    "ID": [5, 2, 12, 7, 3],
    "Status": ['y', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

The data looks like this:

```
df1

   ID  Value
0   1     11
1   2     21
2   3     23
3   4     44
4   5      1

df2

   ID Status
0   5      y
1   2      y
2  12      n
3   7      y
4   3      n
```

Here's the code I used to find the match:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    print(row['ID'])
    if row['ID'] in df2['ID']:
        print("Match")
    else:
        print("No Match")
    print()
```

And the code generated was:

```
1
Match

2
Match

3
Match

4
Match

5
No Match
```

I was hoping to find matches only for indexes 0, 1, and 4, seeing as they're the only ones that had ID #s that was common in both df1 and df2.

Can someone explain why this is doing what it's doing, and the mistake I'm doing that would avoid this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Don't iterate, use `isin` to identify matches. Or `merge`

Comment: @mozway How would I use isin if I was trying to create a column out of it? df1['In Both DFs'] = df1['ID''].isin(df2['ID'] ?

Comment: Yes, or `df1['In Both DFs'] = np.where(df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID']), 'Match', 'No Match')` if you want a string.